# Why does "#" mess up in the editor?

Tags: feature-request, support, design

I like using "#"s when answering a numbered question.  Why does the # make everything big and bold and screw up formatting?  Can we change the default editor formatting?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's the Markdown syntax for header styles.  See https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#headers

Use a backslash '\' before the '#' to make it act like a number sign.

For example, `#1 Doesn't work` becomes:

> ## 1 Doesn't work

Whereas `\#1 Does work` becomes:

> #1 Does work

Comment: Very intuitive!